# Prettier format Array<T> to T[]

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I have a project with react typescript and I'm using prettier to format the code
In TS files I have some interfaces with `Array<T>` and I would like to format to `T[]`

How can I do this?

Comment: if you are using VSCode, you can use its `word replace` tool which lets you use `regex`. you can use `Array<(.*)>` to search and `$1[]` for replace value. note that you should do it multiple times to ensure that the nested `Array<Array<T>>`  get replaced one by one

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan this force me to do it once a while, prettier runs automatically every time I save a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is outside the scope of Prettier, and more in the realm of eslint.

In fact `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` has a rule for this already named `array-type`. See: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/array-type/.

Which labels this as incorrect:

```
const x: Array<string> = ['a', 'b'];
const y: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['a', 'b'];
```

And this as correct:

```
const x: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
const y: readonly string[] = ['a', 'b'];
```

Comment: Will this generate an error or actually change the code?
The ideal was to change the code, so we could keep code structure

Comment: Yes, it's automatically fixable via eslint's built in autofixing. See https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.2.2&fileType=.ts&code=MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgQQE6oIYE8A81UCWYA5gHwwC8MA2gOQa0A0MtARrQLoDcAUKJLCxIASgFMMAE3AAbLGky58RMpRr0mLdtyA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6AQ2mncNqNPRREXAPbRI4MAF8QUoA&tsconfig=&tokens=false. Just click "FIX" by the errors to see how it would alter your code.

Comment: I had to configure the autosave in the vscode settings, is there a way to configure this on eslint configs? So, all time gets eslint ran when saving the file?

Comment: Yes, eslint has lots of settings and code editor integrations. Explaining how to configure those is more than fits in a comment. But I would start by installing the eslint extension for your editor.